# Not enough disk space - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel

I can't install any updates due to this disk space problem. Having reviewed various blog posts on this subject, I've understood that it has something to do with an accumulation of old kernels, but the solutions are not straightforward. Can anyone guide me to a tailor-made solution for my system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) ?

Output of sudo parted:

```
Model: ATA HITACHI HTS72323 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   320GB  320GB  extended
 5      257MB   320GB  320GB  logical                lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4148MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0,00B  4148MB  4148MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 316GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  316GB  316GB  ext4
```

```
df -h | grep -v loop

udev 1,9G 0 1,9G 0% /dev 
tmpfs 382M 11M 371M 3% /run
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 290G 165G 111G 60% /
tmpfs 1,9G 110M 1,8G 6% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5,0M 4,0K 5,0M 1% /run/lock
tmpfs 1,9G 0 1,9G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1 236M 161M 64M 72% /boot
cgmfs 100K 0 100K 0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs 382M 68K 382M 1% /run/user/1000
```

@guiverc
@mikewhatever
@N0rbert
@karel
@vanadium

thanks for pointing out that an answer exists.
I have read that answer but I wasn't confident about following the instructions, so I would appreciate one of you walking me through what needs to be done.

Comment: For a start, update your question with the output of `df -h | grep -v loop` and `sudo parted -l` so we can see what space you have,

Comment: udev                         1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        382M   11M  371M   3% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  290G  165G  111G  60% /
tmpfs                        1,9G  110M  1,8G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    236M  161M   64M  72% /boot
cgmfs                        100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                        382M   68K  382M   1% /run/user/1000

Comment: That was output of df -h | grep -v loop. Output of sudo parted is too long for this comments field. How can I show you that?

Comment: @Mons edit your question for that

Comment: So what should I do now ?

Comment: Problem solved. Up-vote to all who spotted the duplicate question.